# Google-API картинки и аудио

Tags: c#, c++

Добрый день.

Как использовать google Api?

Есть текстовый файл:

```
dog  <tab>    собака
cat  <tab>    кошка
blue <tab>    синий ....
```

Как подключиться к гуглу-картинкам и вытащить первую попавшуюся картинку по слову dog, записать картинку в папку с текстовым файлом и в текстовом файле добавить поле для ссылки, например, `dog.jpeg`.

Точно так же хочется сделать и с произношением, чтоб строка после обработки выглядела

```
dog  <tab>    собака <tab> dog.jpeg<tab>dog.mp3
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать на c++/c#.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Google API работает cледующим образом. Отправляете HTTP-request на https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images с соответствующими HTTP-параметрами. В ответ приходит JSON-объект с параметрами и ссылками на картинки.
Побробно здесь: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

Есть пример на Java, Python и.т.д, там все немного проще, т.к. есть инструменты для работы с HTTP и JSON. Задача сводится к тому чтобы отправить HTTP-запрос (здесь можно посмотреть в сторону Qt, Boost::Asio, libcurl, netlib) и распарсить JSON-ответ (здесь можно смотреть на Qt, libjson, jansson и многое другое)